# Infer types on return value of function, where function parameter is a record of functions

Tags: typescript

I am creating a helper function to create async reducers. I want to create a method which takes in a record (object) of functions, and returns a fully typed result.

Here is a short version of what I have so far:

```
const typed = <T extends keyof any>(
  asyncActions: Record<T, (...args: any[]) => Promise<unknown>>
) => asyncActions;

const result = typed({
  func: (praram: string) => Promise.resolve(),
  func2: (praram: number) => Promise.resolve(),
});
```

The resulting type of `result` is: `const result: Record<"func" | "func2", (...args: any[]) => Promise<unknown>>`.

As you can see the keys of the return value are being infered correctly, but I cannot work out how to force the infer of the functions. Is this at all possible? Or am I barking up an extremely tall tree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of the properties in `asyncActions` is widened to `(...args: any[]) => Promise<unknown>` because it is *annotated* as such, where the only thing the compiler can infer is `K`, the keys.  Instead you might want to just annotate the type of `asyncActions` as a generic type `T` which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `Record<keyof T, (...args: any[]) => Promise<unknown>>`:

```
const typed = <T extends Record<keyof T, (...args: any[]) => Promise<unknown>>>(
    asyncActions: T
) => asyncActions;

const result = typed({
    func: (praram: string) => Promise.resolve(),
    func2: (praram: number) => Promise.resolve(),
});

/* const result: {
    func: (praram: string) => Promise<void>;
    func2: (praram: number) => Promise<void>;
} */
```

As you see, the type of `result` is now reasonably strong, and the compiler knows specifically what the parameters of each property will be:

```
result.func("hello"); // okay
result.func(123); // error
result.func2(123); // okay
result.func2("hello"); // error
```

as well as the return types:

```
result.func("hello").then(v => v.toUpperCase()) // error!
// ----------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~
// Property 'toUpperCase' does not exist on type 'void'.
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-KPRmMRv30lqOhAwADkUDtDuWLsMKZgqBAyVmIFgRAMsHAcCQyFTqNQKf49iAA)