# How do I retain function parameter types in a returned Record of functions

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

I have a simple function which takes an object of functions as a parameter and returns that object.

```js
type Func = () => void
type Async = () => Promise<void>

const foo = <K extends string>(fns: Record<K, Func | Async) => fns
```

Ideally each function should be able to accept parameters and retain the type signature of the parameters in the object when it is returned from the function. Something like this:

```js
const fns = foo({
  foo: (a: string, b: string) => {}
  asyncFoo: async (a: string, b: string) => {} 
})

// typescript doesn't know that a, b are parameters
// will complain that I am passing these parameters
// since they don't exist in the type signature
fns.foo('a', 'b')
await fns.asyncFoo('a', 'b')
```

How do I type this function so the object of functions returned from it can infer/retain the parameter types?

Side note: the actual code for this is inspired from `@redux-toolkit` and a great example of this kind of behavior is with `createSlice()` and how the actions retain the payload typings from the reducers passed to the function.

Comment: Does it only need to work with `Func` + `Async`, or with *any* function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66201831/infer-types-on-return-value-of-function-where-function-parameter-is-a-record-of?rq=1) after posting this lol.

Basically I needed to add this typing:

```js
type Func = (...args: any[]) => void
type AsyncFunc = (...args: any[]) => Promise<void>

const foo = <K extends Record<keyof K, Func | AsyncFunc>>(fns: K) => fns
```